How to Deal with Harassment Pranksters in Public?
Harassment pranksters create content that solely involves harassing people.
They make people visibly uncomfortable and, in some cases, creating potentially unsafe situations.
My general strategy in uncomfortable public situations is to deescalate.
However, the goal of harassment pranksters seems to be the exact opposite, they try to escalate the situation they've caused.
From my very limited experience with pranksters, it works to just walk away and not engage with them at all.
But, I've seen online content where that doesn't seem to help.
What strategy could I follow if walking away doesn't end the interaction or if I want to assist strangers that get harassed?

What sort of harassment have you been witnessing? Have you tried anything else?

How does walking away not end your involvement?

@YosefBaskin Google for "youtube prankster jailed". If a prankster enters your home, would you walk away? If it's in the public, you walk away, and the prankster follows you, how does walking away end your involvement? There are "pranksters" where your choice is between becoming the victim or using violence.

@BentleyCarpenter I haven't encountered a situation where I couldn't just walk away. Regarding what I think I would do: I'd call the police on the pranksters and if possible get staff involved.

@YosefBaskin I admit, it's a quite unrealistic scenario, but as gnasher729 pointed out these scenarios exist, be it in public transport or in a restaurant. Eventually, I'll have the chance to leave, but until then I'd have to endure the harassment. Also, it doesn't feel right to walk away, if you don't want to leave or the "prankster" then harasses somebody else.

There are sadly people making money by harassing others in public or in their own homes, filming it, and posting it on social media.

Be as boring as possible.  If possible, walk away.  Otherwise, give them the least reaction possible while keeping yourself safe.  Don't argue with them, get upset, tell them off, etc.
As they have the primary goal of instigating and filming a dramatic situation for likes and views, they will generally move on quickly once they realize you aren't going to provide entertainment value.
